# I have a sigma auto F 70-300 lens. I want to use it on a new Canon77D camera but the mount on the camera and the lens are different can I use adapter

Tags: equipment-recommendation

I have a Sigma lens auto focus 70-300 open 55mm mount. My camera is a
77D canon mount 67mm. Can I use an adapter? The mount size is not the same size. If so,what adapter do I need? The lens dose not fit on the camera body.

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use lens brand X on interchangeable lens camera brand Y?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/62000/can-i-use-lens-brand-x-on-interchangeable-lens-camera-brand-y) BTW, SIgma makes lenses with many mount types, so you'll need to know which type it is.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.